# Initiate google map from middleware in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, express, handlebars.js

I am working on marking a Google Map dynamically, I can initiate the map in a `layout.hbs`

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{google_browser_key}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6810038, 12.6033823),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: false
    });
</script>
```

But I don't wish to broadcast my API key to the world, is it possible to setup a callback to the `app.js`, where you connect each `document` with the `maps.googleapis.com`?

I tried to use the router, but I am missing `document` or `window` variables:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.title = req.Globalize.formatMessage('strings/title');
    res.locals.google_browser_key = "";

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6810038, 12.6033823),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: false
    });

    next();
});
```